# Negate a bind variable

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I am using APEX 5.0 and I have a query such as:

```
Select * FROM table where condition = :BIND_VARIABLE
```

I have a list which dynamically fills in the bind variable. The list has two values which the bind variable can take:

```
Value 1
Everything except value 1
```

'Everything else' value which is returned is user controlled so I can't have an EXISTS or IN because I do not know all the values that will be in there.

Is it possible to do something like

Select * FROM table where condition = !'Value 1'

Comment: instead of `=` use `<>`

Comment: but then when I need it to be Value 1 it will be need to be = . It is a select List in ORACLE APEX, I can't change the query dynamically. I need a query which can handle both scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't remember exact syntax for oracle substring, but you can try something like:

```
Select *
FROM table
where
(condition = :BIND_VARIABLE AND SUBSTR(:BIND_VARIABLE, 1, 1) <> '!')
OR
(condition <> SUBSTR(:BIND_VARIABLE, 2) AND SUBSTR(:BIND_VARIABLE, 1, 1) = '!')
```

so, if your value starts with `!` symbol - you will look for all except passed value

Comment: If I select 'Value1' it returns all the values 1 only, but if I select '!Value1' as the bind variable then it returns all including Value1

Comment: @user2924127 I've just updated, check substr in second statement